# Dynamic content based on Wordpress URL path

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress template called `locations.php` and a Wordpress page called Locations with a permalink of `www.domain.com/locations`.

`locations.php` goes a good job of generating dynamic content based on the $_GET of the URL. Ex: `/location?state=NY`, will generate content from a custom table that applies to state=NY

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mh_locations'; // do not forget about tables prefix
$state = htmlspecialchars($_GET['state'], ENT_QUOTES);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE state='" . $state . "'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach ( $result as $result ) 
{
    echo $result->name;
    echo "<br />";
};
```

So in this case, I can have one Locations page, and one locations.php template to populate different state information.

What I actually need is to have a more flexible permalink structure to allow different variables in the URL path.

Ex: /locations/NY, will do the same as the above but without the $_GET.
The issue is that since the NY page doesn't exist, Wordpress returns a 404.

Is there a way to "block off" a certain path structure and allow all the extra paths I want?

I would wind up with URL's like:

- /locations/NY
- /locations/NY/Manhattan
- /locations/NY/Product1
- /locations/Product2

So in essence, all virtual, limitless paths, but all under the same path root of /locations/.

And from there some fancy `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`'s can use the paths for the query.

*Updated to sanitize GET

Comment: This is incredibly unsafe! You can't EVER put user input directly into a SQL query. It has to be sanitised first.

Comment: you should better use CPT custom post types in wordpress if you want permalink structure same as the wordpress uses for post or pages.

Comment: Yes, agreed! Sorry, that was a quick concept example.

Comment: You want to go here and also read the Codex links at the end of the post... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48487/how-to-retrieve-get-variables-from-rewritten-urls